# Bayesian Estimator

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

The Bayesian estimator is defined as $f* = \text{argmin}_f \epsilon(f)$ where $\epsilon(f)$ is the error function.

What is the Bayes estimator for the error function $\epsilon(f) = \sum_x \sum_y | y- f(x)| p(x,y)$?

I know I should differentiate with respect to $f$ and set this equal to zero but am struggling because of the modulus. I wrote $|y-f(x)| = \sqrt{(y-f(x))^2}$ and then I get

$\frac{\partial \epsilon(f)}{\partial f} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_x \sum_y \frac{1}{\sqrt{(y-f(x))^2}} 2 (y-f(x)) \times (-1) p(x,y) = - \sum_x \sum_y |y-f(x)| p(x,y)$

There must be a mistake here since if I set this expression equal to zero (for maximum) there is no way for me to isolate and solve for the $f(x)$ term.

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting$$\epsilon(f) = \sum_x \sum_y | y- f(x)| p(x,y)$$as$$\mathbb E[|Y-f(X)|]$$where the expectation $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ is computed under the joint distribution $p(x,y)$, the solution to$$\arg_f\min_f \mathbb E[|Y-f(X)|]$$is obtained by solving for each possible value $x$ of $X$ the programme$$\arg_\delta\min_\delta \mathbb E[|Y-\delta||X=x]$$ which leads to$$\delta^\star=\text{median}(Y|X=x)$$(as shown e.g. in [my book](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw), Proposition 2.5.5).

> The Bayes estimator in this case is thus the conditional median of $Y$
>   given $X$.

Comment: Hello. Can you explain how to get from second last line to last line? Where does median come from? Thanks.

Comment: I mean, it makes sense I suppose to pick the point in the middle of the domain to minimise the absolute difference. But can we show it algebraically?

Answer (score 0):

You have eliminated the sign from your derivative with the square root.

A quite nice explanation can be found here:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-derivative-of-modulus-function

You will see that you are still setting out for a difficult task. To my knowledge, such optimization problems are typically solved numerically only.